# Force flash on native mobile camera

Tags: javascript, html, camera

I am taking a photo with the user's native camera application via HTML, like so:

```
    <input
      type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      capture="camera" />
```

This opens the user's native camera application and gives a reject/confirm dialogue, which fits our use case perfectly.

Firstly and most importantly - can we force the flash using this or any other method?

Also, it would be nice to force the rear camera, but this is not necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Nice one, but I don't think that's possible using normal HTML. The spec doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first comment is correct, but by using a client-side image EXIF data library it seems that we can accept/reject photos based on flash fired.